# How to get the system type in SFTP?

Tags: java, windows, unix, jsch

In FTP Client there is a method called getSystem name that fetches the system type name from the server and returns the string.

I was wondering if there is a same method in SFTP that fetches the system type name from the server?

If none how can i get the system type name through SFTP.

Comment: FTP is a protocol, it doesn't have methods. You are probably talking about some Java FTP API, which one? Apache commons-net? And which API is used for SFTP?

Comment: Apache commons-net. the FTPClient getSystemType. JSCH is used for SFTP

Comment: Right, I missed the tag. You have to realize that FTP and SFTP are absolutely not related to each other, they are two entirely different protocols. What is possible in one is not necessarily available in the other.

Comment: i was wondering someone could help me on how to get the system type name from the server. Thanks for your comment.